# Workaround for Google Hangouts to load consistently in Firefox

Tags: google-hangouts, firefox

Running Firefox (51.0.1), Google Hangouts will not load properly on about 60% of my attempts to load it.

It will load the background image, the elements, but will not load the Conversations list:
[image: Hangouts without Conversation list]

To access the Google Hangout site, I will just reload the page until it does load correctly. Do I have a setting I can change to ensure it does load correctly every time?

Comment: This is one of those questions that straddle [SU] and [Webapps.SE], I think.  Can you narrow it down to any add-ons you may have installed (start in Safe mode or disable them one-by-one)?  I'm a Firefox person, and I've found with some of these things that the best thing to do is hop over to Chrome for a minute, even if it's a mild betrayal :)

Comment: Current version of Firefox is 56 and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google or Mozilla appear to have resolved this, either with an update to the site or the browser (Firefox 52.1.0).